# Where should I put properties file for simplelogger for slf4j?

Tags: java, slf4j

I have `myapp.jar` file, and I put a **simplelogger.properties** file at the same directory. But it seems it won't load the properties defined.

I find it always to find the correct place to put the properties files. Any suggestions/guides?

Comment: How do you launch your app? What's its classpath?

Comment: what's the command that you run to launch jvm? Waht logger type you use behind slf4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's loaded from the root of the classpath. You either need to package the file inside the root of your JAR file, or put the directory containing the file into your application's classpath when you run it.

Comment: If you run an executable jar (`java -jar`), adding things to the classpath is tricky.